# Inject AsyncPipe in another pipe

Tags: angular

**Use case** : I defined a `CustomError` like this :

```
interface {
  message?: string;
  i18nMessage?: string;
}
```

And I define a `DisplayErrorPipe` to display the error. If `message` is defined, the pipe returns it. Else, if `i18nMessage` is defined, the pipe returns a `Observable<string>` (which will emit the translated error).

So the pipe should be used like this :

```
{{ customError | displayError }}
```

`DisplayErrorPipe` might return an Observable but I would like to avoid having to pipe `async` every time

```
{{ customError | displayError | async }}
```

Hence, I need to inject `AsyncPipe` in `DisplayErrorPipe` so that I can automatically pipe `async` when the pipe returns an `Observable<string>`.

So I tried :

```
constructor(private asyncPipe: AsyncPipe) {}
```

but I get an error :

> NullInjectorError: No provider for AsyncPipe!

I can't find which module I should import in order to be able to inject `AsyncPipe`.

Until now, the only solution I have is :

```
constructor(private _ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  const asyncPipe = new AsyncPipe(_ref);
}
```

This works but is likely to break if the constructor of AsyncPipe changes.

**Question** : How to properly inject `AsyncPipe` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to register the AsyncPipe as a provider in the module that component is declared in. I think Angular doesn't register them as services by default in the DI system.

Comment: I had to inject ChangeDetectorRef as well but it worked : `providers: [ AsyncPipe, ChangeDetectorRef as Provider ]`.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar problem, and get to a similar solution but I am getting an error ```this._ref.markForCheck is not a function```, I have all my pipes in a separated module. Is necessarily to export the AsyncPipe and ChangeDetectorRef? if so, how can I make it?

Comment: Having the same problem as @ErnestoAlfonso

Comment: Hi, I could not archive this, i change my approach to use the asyncPipe en the template like ```'myVar' | myPipe | async```

Comment: Works like a charm in angular 14
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pccaut?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdisplay-error.pipe.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fpipe-consumer%2Fpipe-consumer.component.html